# What is a good photograph

Tags: digital

This might sound little lame,

Anybody please explain(if possible with example)

what is a good photograph ? How we can decide a photo which is good ? for an example if you are in a Deciding panel how you would decide or elect a photo as winner of a photography contest ?

What are the technical aspects that we need to consider ?

Not considering taste here

[image: This is vivan Maires one of the photo] How actually judges judge theses photos.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not considering taste here? Oh... that is probably the only real answer...

Does it have a good colour or grayscale shades? Is it in focus, is it not blurry?

Do those technical details really matter?

I have seen out of focus photos where the main subject is so unique or dramatic that those details don't matter. This one comes to my mind:

[image]

In my opinion, as in all the arts, taste and opinion are the only thing that at the end matter. A photo of my baby is the best baby photo of all time!

Of course there will always be people that think that a really dumb or disgusting proportion is art.

I'm adapting a quote from Johann S. Bach:
“The aim and final end of all arts should be none other than refreshment of the soul.”

*"A good photo should say something, a story, a feeling, a posture, a point of view, something new, something old.  Perhaps there is a case that all that a good photo speaks is silence."*

Comment: As Marshall McLuhan pointed out, low-resolution media such as your example photo can actually be *more* engaging, by requiring more activity on the part of the viewer's brain. :)